# How prove this $pq|p^{aq}+q^{ap}+a$

Tags: number-theory

> let $p,q$ are prime numbers,show that
>   for any $(p,q)$,there must exist positive integer numbers $a$,such
>   $$pq|p^{aq}+q^{ap}+a$$

since I consider this problem,and I found this problem is maybe from this http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1704114&sid=3b8ef31515f3721e84dda4acdff4823f#p1704114

Korean Olympiad Finals (2007-4) problem is this

Find all pairs $ (p, q)$ of primes such that $ p^p+q^q+1$ is divisible by $ pq$.

But for my problem I can't prove it,Thank you,and I think this is nice problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's equivalent to
$$q^a+a\equiv0 \pmod p \\p^a+a\equiv0 \pmod q.$$

> **Lemma 1:** If $q^a+a\equiv0 \pmod p$ then 
>   $q^{a+kp(p-1)}+a+kp(p-1)\equiv0 \pmod p.$
>
> **Lemma 2:** If $(p,q)=1$, then $$q^a+a\equiv0 \pmod p$$
>    has $p-1$ solutions when $1\leq a\leq p(p-1),$ and they are distinct $\mod p-1.$
>
> *Proof:* Let $1\leq a,b,\leq p(p-1),$ if $a≠b,a\equiv b\pmod {p-1}$ then $q^a+a\not\equiv q^b+b\pmod p$, otherwise we get $a\equiv b\pmod p$, a contradiction.

Hence we can pick $x$ such that $x\equiv (p-1,q-1) \pmod {p-1}$ and $q^x+x\equiv0 \pmod p$.

Also, we can pick $y$ such that $y\equiv (p-1,q-1) \pmod {q-1}$ and $p^y+y\equiv0 \pmod q$.

**Case 1:** If $(p,q-1)=(q,p-1)=1$, then by Chinese remainder theorem, there exist $a$ such that

$$a\equiv x \pmod {p(p-1)} \\a\equiv y \pmod {q(q-1)}.$$
Then by lemma $1$, we are done.

**Case 2:** If $p<q$ and $q\equiv1 \pmod p$, then it's equivalent to
$$1+a\equiv0 \pmod p \\p^a+a\equiv0 \pmod q.$$
By lemma $2$, we can pick $a\equiv -1\pmod {q-1},$ then $1+a\equiv0 \pmod p$, we are done.

Comment: Hello,can you explain why  equivalent to   $$q^a+a\equiv 0(mod p),p^a+a\equiv (mod q)$$

Comment: @china math If $(p,q)=1$ then $q^p\equiv q\pmod p,q^{pa}\equiv q^a\pmod p$

Comment: I think you just need to use [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an incomplete attempt at a solution.  I am posting it in the hopes that the ideas contained within can be used by someone else to find a complete solution before I can.

Let $p,q$ be fixed primes, and let $f(a)=p^{aq}+q^{ap}+a$.  If $S_p=\{a\in \mathbb N \mid f(a)\equiv 0 \pmod p \}$, and similarly for $S_q$, then the problem is equivalent to showing $S_p \cap S_q \neq \emptyset$.

Let us examine $S_p$ more closely.  By Fermat's little theorem,  $f(a)\equiv 0^{aq} + q^{a}+a \pmod p$.  Therefore, if $f(a)\equiv b \pmod p$, then 
$$f(a+b(p-1)) \equiv q^a (q^{p-1})^b + a -b \equiv q^a (1)^b +a -b  \equiv b-b \pmod p,$$
and so we have an effective way of producing (some of the) elements of $S_p$.  In particular, this argument shows that $S_p$ must be $(p(p-1))$-periodic in the sense that $p(p-1)+S_p\subset S_p$.  Additionally, we have $p-1\in S_p$

By symmetry, $S_q$ is $q(q-1)$-periodic and contains $q-1$.  If the linear progressions $(p-1)+p(p-1)\mathbb Z$ and $(q-1)+q(q-1)\mathbb Z$ intersect, then any (positive) element in the intersection will be a solution to the original problem.  Unfortunately, I do not currently see why this should be the case, and I need to sleep.